# run multiple queries with spool in sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I know I can run multiple queries saved in file with GO statement between them and save the result into file with spool command
but this will save the whole result into a single file
how can I export each query result into a dedicated file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use multiple spool statements between each SELECT

eg, `spool c:\filenme.txt`